# What's the antonym of "occurrence"?

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking for the antonym of *occurrence*. I want to use it in this sentence:

> Based on the occurrence/[antonym] of signals, decisions will be made.

The context is scientific. I would like to have just one word for this particular sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typical scientific/technical jargon in this kind of sentence is this:

> occurrence/nonoccurrence

and

> presence/absence

Comment: Seconding presence/absence, occurrence/nonoccurrence makes much less sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest *[absence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absence)* might be the word you are looking for, in the sense of *the fact of being without something*.

Answer (score 0):

`Lack` might work too. Based on the occurrence or lack of signals, decisions will be made.